# The definition of tori - topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, surfaces

The question may seem silly, but I do not find the answer.

For me, the $n-$torus is "an sphere with $n$ holes".

Topologically, this is called the connected sum of $n$ tori, is it right?

What about the $T^n=\overbrace{S^1\times \cdots \times S^1}^{n \,times}$, what is its name and what are its properties?

***Do the two surfaces have some relation?***

Thank you so much.

Comment: "sphere with holes" is not really mathematic. The $n-$Torus (or the torus in dimension $n$) is **by definition** $\underbrace{\mathbb S^1\times ...\times \mathbb S^1}_{n\ times}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Call it the $n$-holed torus :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it's true (but it is). I'm laughing at myself now. Thank you very much, Mr. Shifrin.@TedShifrin I am thinking how it would be named in portuguese..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-torus is a torus of dimension $n$, it is defined to be the cartesian product of $n$ one-dimensional circle. This is roughly a $n$-dimensional sphere with a $n$-dimensional hole.

What you describe as a sphere with $m$ holes is indeed the connected sum of $m$ different copies of a $2$-dimensional torus.

Those two surfaces are not homeomorphic whenever $n\neq 2$ or $n=2$ and $m\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, so the "sphere with $2$ holes" is not called bitorus, right? Thank you

Comment: Although one sometimes sees the "$n$-torus" terminology in the context of a "sphere with $n$ holes", or the "bitorus" terminology in the $n=2$ context, as you can see that terminology clashes with established usage of higher dimensional toruses. For that reason, the "$n$-torus" and "bitorus" terminologies should be avoided in those contexts, but one might still find older books which use those terminologies.

Comment: @LeeMosher perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is the n-Torus:

$$
T^n = S^1 \times \dots \times S^1
$$

See the wiki entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#n-dimensional_torus

Comment: Thank you so much!